# Image picker in web doesn't work on deploy?

Tags: flutter, imagepicker, flutter-image-picker

I have set up image picker and it works perfectly in localhost but not at all once deployed to web.

I've looked at the web implementation and I think I have done it as it says there but it still doesn't work so I don't know if I missed something?

My code:

```
 File? _pickedImage;

  Uint8List webImage = Uint8List(8);

  Future<void> _getFromGallery() async {
    if (!kIsWeb) {
      final ImagePicker getImage = ImagePicker();
      XFile? image = await getImage.pickImage(source: ImageSource.gallery);
      if (image != null) {
        var selected = File(image.path);
        setState(() {
          _pickedImage = selected;
        });
      } else {
        const Text('Something went wrong.');
      }
    } else {
      final ImagePicker getImage = ImagePicker();
      XFile? image = await getImage.pickImage(source: ImageSource.gallery);
      if (image != null) {
        var f = await image.readAsBytes();
        setState(() {
          webImage = f;
          _pickedImage = File('a');
        });
      } else {
        const Text('Something went wrong.');
      }
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For anyone with the same issue - just had to fun flutter clean then flutter pub get and it worked.